# Make koGrid respect observable properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I've been writing an app with the kogrid, recently I changed my datasource from an array of objects to an array of knockout objects. However, to my surprise when I update the observable properties within my objects the grid is not updated.

Here is my data array:

```
self.gridData = ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable("joe"), age: ko.observable(5) }
]);
```

when I update the age property nothing happens on the grid:

```
self.gridData()[0].age(6);
```

does anyone have a good answer for why this is?

### Update

I've answered the question [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21860330/2391620), but does anyone know why the kogrid would be caching the unwrapped values?

Comment: Isn't gridData a field?  I've never actually used knockout, but you seem to be calling it like a function.

Comment: @rogue_js that bit of syntax is actually fine, it's Knockout's way of retrieving an observable's value.

Comment: Can you include some more info on how you wire everything together, possibly create a repro? The code you posted looks just fine.

Comment: @Jeroen Does my answer below help the question make more sense? Do you know why the values should be cached?

Comment: Well, caching is often for performance, but a proper feature in any case. If the cache isn't being invalidated correctly that may be a bug in kogrid, but the bug can also be in your code. Impossible to tell without a repro :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the kogrid source and found this line in [src/classes/row.js](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/blob/master/src/classes/row.js#L66)

```
self.getProperty = function (path) {
    return self.propertyCache[path] || (self.propertyCache[path] = window.kg.utils.evalProperty(self.entity, path));
};
```

it looks like the property cache is caching the unwrapped value of the property we're accessing in the default [cell template](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/blob/master/src/templates/cellTemplate.html):

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': 'kgCellText colt' + $index()}, html: $data.getProperty($parent)"></div>
```

(Note: $data in the template is the column, which has a getProperty wrapper for row.getProperty)

I simply removed the line to cache property values like this:

```
self.getProperty = function (path) {
    return window.kg.utils.evalProperty(self.entity, path);
};
```